# How should I do the Vuex with one page of Vue and .NET Core?

Tags: vue.js, .net-core, vuex

I have a .NET Core 3.x project, where I also have added an Web API. On one of the pages I have a Vue-page.
Because I was not competent enough to set up a Vue-project inside the .net-project. I decided to have Vue on only one page (to show data).
So how can I use Vuex, when it is only one page that uses Vue?
The most important part of the site is this page because it will be i kind of lookup in the catalog. And to do that I want to browse through data stored in Vuex.

Is this possible. Or is it another way that is easier?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can still use vuex with the vue cdn or within a script tag. When you initialize a new vue element, import the store variable and pass it into the vue element. You will then be able to access like normal.

Something like:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Comment: Thank you. Why did you get -1?

Comment: This did not work. How to I import the store variable?

Comment: The store variable is something that you create, you can make one in a separate script, or write it in your vue script. It would be something like const store = new Vuex(...insert vuex information...). Then you would bring that store variable into your vue instance like above